# Запуск приложения python на сервере Ubuntu через symlink на Windows?

Tags: python, windows

Написал графическое приложение на `python`. Сейчас оно находится на моей рабочей машине  c `Ubuntu` в `PyCharm`. Приложение подключается и работает с базой данных `MySql` и с файлами находящимися на `ubuntu-server` в нашей локальной сети.

Теперь, не хотелось бы компилировать это приложение для `Windows` (для других пользователей), хочу сделать так: Перенести это приложение на `ubuntu-server` и чтобы пользователи `Windows` стартовали его путем запуска скажем `symlink` c `ubuntu-server`.

Есть ли другие варианты (я хочу сделать это без `web`)?
Или только вариант установки интерпретатора `python` на `Windows`?

Comment: Что приложение делает то? На самом деле через веб проще всего было бы. Браузеры есть у всех и на любой ОС, а веб-приложение на `Flask` написать можно за 5 минут. Но вообще, повторюсь, смотря что приложение делает. Можно и через каталог на убунте общаться - пользователи туда что-то кладут, скрипт всё время там крутится, обнаруживает новый файл, обрабатывает его и кладёт опять же в другой каталог результат, откуда пользователь его забирает. Вариантов много можно придумать.

Answer (score 0):

1. запаковать приложение в exe. скачивать и запускать.
2. установить X сервер на Виндовс. Запускать приложение на сервере по ssh - картинку получать на винде.
3. установить X сервер на сервере. Картинку передавать по rdp/vnc/spice
4. QT_QPA_PLATFORM=qvnc - без X сервера - напрямую в внц.
5. [QT_QPA_PLATFORM=webgl](https://www.qt.io/blog/2018/11/23/qt-quick-webgl-release-512) - картинка в браузер.